# Horror Comic-locked in an iron maiden

Tags: story-identification, comics, horror

I remember as a kid reading an old horror comic of my dad's, maybe from 60s or 70s, and one of the issue's tales ended with a character being locked inside an iron maiden coffin with spikes. Can't remember which comic or issue? Haunt of Fear?  Weird?  Thanks!

Comment: Take a look at this [guide](http://meta.scifi.stackexchange.com/a/9337/68872) to help jog your memory and [edit] any more details. Also, take a look at our [tour] to get a better understanding of our site and earn your first [badge](http://scifi.stackexchange.com/help/badges)!

Answer (score 5):

In *Haunt of Fear* #8 (vol. 1, 1951), there's a story called "The Irony of Death!" A man marries his boss's daughter and throws the boss into molten steel at the mill he thus inherits. When they make an iron maiden from this steel, he steps inside and it closes.